# Servlet mapping and HTTP status 404

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I have a problem with my Servlet implementation. I'm using Apache Tomcat as the Servlet engine and Eclipse as the IDE. First I created a *search.html* as follow:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>FirstServler</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="/myServlet" method="get">
        Name : <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="name" SIZE="18"/>
        <input type="submit" value="OK">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Then I created a servlet, called Servlet1:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet("/Servlet1")
public class Servlet1 extends HttpServlet
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Servlet1() 
    {
        super();
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
    {
        String s= request.getParameter("name");
        response.getWriter().write(s);
    }
}
```

And finally the web.xml, located in WebContent\WEB-INF:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-         instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"   id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>Servlet</display-name>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>servlet1</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>Servlet1</servlet-class>
 </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>servlet1</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/myServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  </web-app>
```

When I enter data inside the input box of search.html and press "OK" I get the following error:

```
HTTP Status 404 - /Servlet1.0/es1
type Status report
message /Servlet1.0/es1
description The requested resource is not available.
```

I think there are some mistakes with web.xml. In fact, if I change the url-pattern into es1, I don't get an error.

Comment: Have you checked your console to check what exception are you getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The err says: "The requested resource is not available". My best guess is the server can't find the `Servlet1` class.

Two Suggestions:

- The name of `@WebServlet("/Servlet1")` doesn't match `<servlet-name>servlet1</servlet-name>`, the previous uses 'S' while the latter uses 's'. Try to use the same name.
- Try to move the `Servlet1` class to a package instead of put it under the default package.